# Turn user supplied string into a literal string, to append a pre-defined regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a user supplied string, that I then need to turn into a Regular Expression where their string is treated as a literal, then I append a pre-written regular expression on the end.

Essentially, a way to say "what the user supplied, followed by this pattern".

This makes me think I may need to sanitise the user supplied string, to escape meta-characters.

As an example, this is what I tried

`\\ Replace "\" with "\\"

String rE = userText.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");

\\ Replace . with \.

rE = rE.replaceAll(".", "\\.");`

However this fails with the following message, when matching the \ escaping

```
Execution aborted because of unhandled exception:
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
^ at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1725)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1478)
```

Is there an easier way to do this? I suspect there's a built in method to make potential regEx's into literals, but I can't find it.

I've had a look through similar questions, but none seem to want to treat the users input string as a literal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Pattern.quote`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) Method to quote the user supplied string as *literal* pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Pattern.quote` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) to escape all metacharacters or escape sequences:

```
String rE = Pattern.quote("\\");
```

> This method produces a `String` that can be used to create a `Pattern` that would match the string `s` as if it were a literal pattern.